# How can i use $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] to find that user came from google?

Tags: php, search

I haven't used `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` before and i dont knw how i can use that to find that user came to my site by clicking on a link in Google search results. User can come from google.com, google.co.uk etc....

Help much appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
$url = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
$query = parse_url ($url, PHP_URL_QUERY);
$host = parse_url ($url, PHP_URL_HOST);
if (strstr ($query, 'q=') && strstr ($host, 'google.')) {
    // user came from google
else {
    // user didnt come from google
}
```

Comment: However, be careful when using the HTTP_REFERER. It is sent in the page headers, so it may easily be modified by a client. Do not treat it any less carefully than you would a $_POST or $_GET variable.

Comment: so is there a better solution than HTTP_REFERER?

Comment: Does this work anymore now that Google transferred over to https and https supposedly doesn't pass HTTP_REFERER data?

Answer (score 1):

That's my solution which doesn't give any warnings when referrer doesn't exists from the page request.

```
public function doesUserCameFromCrawler() {
    $crawlerList=array("google.","yandex.","bing.");

    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])) {
        $referringPage = parse_url( $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] );
        if ( isset( $referringPage['host'] )) {
            $referringHost = $referringPage['host'];
            foreach ($crawlerList as $crawler) {
                if (strpos(strtolower($referringHost),$crawler) !== FALSE) {
                    return TRUE;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return FALSE;
}
```