# Get requesting file path in php

Tags: php, file-get-contents, http-referer

I have a file check.php which is called in another php file call.php using `file_get_contents('check.php')`. I want to maintain a history of files calling check.php by getting the url of requesting files. I have tried `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` but it is not helping. Is there any way I can find out the url of requesting file?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: How to get referrer URL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16374704/php-how-to-get-referrer-url)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `debug_backtrace()` inside `check.php`..

```
$debug = debug_backtrace();
```

..to display the calling file..

```
echo $debug[0]['file']);
```

..and Log this somehwere..

Comment: It's not working for me. $debug[0]['file'] is empty.