# How to know which page sent the form action with PHP

Tags: php, html

I'm new to php. I'd like to know if there is a way to retrieve the page who sent the request.

Let's say I have a file called Page.php with the following bit of code:

```
<form action="script.php" method="post">...</form>
```

Is there some way to dynamically get the value "Page.php" on script.php?

Comment: Put it in a hidden field and submit it. You can't necessarily rely on referrers

Comment: Depends on how reliable you need it to be.  You can check the referrer header or perhaps put a hidden form field and check that, both of which can be spoofed by the user.

Comment: [debug_backtrace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php)

Comment: @Machavity That dupe, is not a reliable method, and here's why http://stackoverflow.com/a/6023980/1415724

Comment: @Fred-ii- Yeah, I mentioned that in my comment. if you think it needs to be a different dupe, feel free to change it

Comment: Put a hidden field in your HTML form with the `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` to get the full URL of the submitting form. This, just like `HTTP_REFERER` can be manipulated by the user so should not be relied upon. I would suggest authenticating the value, but that's way outside the scope of this Q

Comment: @Machavity I think there are quite a few ways to do this actually. However, I said it was not reliable, I didn't say it was wrong; 2 different animals here ;-)

Comment: Hmm, thanks for commenting. Sorry if it is a duplicate I did not know how to phrase my question to php specific stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` will give you the referrer page's URL if there exists any. More information here: [PHP: How to get referrer URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16374704/php-how-to-get-referrer-url)

Please note that using HTTP_REFERER isn't reliable, it's value is dependent on the HTTP Referer header sent by the browser or client application to the server.  More information here: [How reliable is HTTP_REFERER?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6023941/how-reliable-is-http-referer/6023980#6023980) In other words it can't be trusted but it can help you :).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6023980/1415724 `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` is not reliable.

Comment: ok, thanks I edited.

Comment: Thanks for answering, I guess I'll use it for now.