# Make that link only for when it comes from a specific page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I wanted to know if it is possible that only the content of a web page is shown as long as it comes from a link for example:

```
mipagina.com/paso1.php to ► mipagina.com/paso2.php
```

And in this way if the person tries to enter `mipagina.com/paso2.php` directly with the URL, it is not allowed to either see nothing or show an error message.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/referrer

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16374704/php-how-to-get-referrer-url

Comment: How would you do to implement it? I do not use a database, I'm a user in Spanish, sorry for writing errors

Comment: Check to see if referer matches and show hide the content.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: How to get referrer URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16374704/php-how-to-get-referrer-url)

Comment: If this need to be secure then relying on referer is a mistake. The referer header can be set by the user.

Comment: @jkjul are you using `start_session()`?

Comment: @jkjul check my answer, it may help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$ref = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
if(isset($ref[0])) {
    $protocol = strtolower(parse_url($ref)['scheme']) === 'https' ? 'https':'http';
    echo (strtolower($ref) === $protocol . '://mipagina.com/paso1.php') ? 'welcome':'You can\'t access this page directly.';  
} else {
   echo 'You can\'t access this page directly.';
}
```

*Ps: don't rely on the `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` as it's not always sent to the server and can be changed by the application user hence vulnerability increases.*

Comment: very well the code detects when I enter directly by url and I redigire to the page of error assigned the problem that I have with this code is that it works if I enter from any page as long as it is for a link by saying step5523.php contains a link to step2.php and the same keep going when you should show the error message since the only entry should only be by step1.php, I would like it to work the same but only show the web and the welcome message only when it comes from a page in specific in this case paso1.php

Comment: I didn't quietly understand, but, what this code does is simply: if a request comes to `page2.php` that its not from `page1.php` it will be notified via a message saying "You can't access this page directly." You can provide a screenshot of your issue or explain more your needs so I can help you further. Another time, relying on `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` is really a bad idea, you can implement tracking by yourself and it's not that hard to do.

Comment: Excuse me, what happens is that I'm allowed to enter any part that contains the link, I want you to only enter when the link is in step1.php for example if I put a link to step123.php let me enter same step2.php when I should send an error

Comment: I really don't get it, the condition of accessing is simple: if the referrer = 'page1.php' show 'welcome' else show 'you cant access this page' ! But the access condition is clear so I'll write here for you changing the `ternary operator` by corresponding `if` and `else` statements: `if(strtolower($ref) === $protocol . '://mipagina.com/paso1.php') { echo 'welcome'; } else { echo 'You can\'t access this page directly.'; }`

Comment: Thanks, if I have just tried it but the problem is that it is in a step2.php from another page that is not step1.php keeps entering me normally when I should send the error message, it is only sending the error message when I enter by URL

Comment: `<?php
 
$ref = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
if(isset($ref[0])) {
    $protocol = strtolower(parse_url($ref)['scheme']) === 'https' ? 'https':'http';
    echo (strtolower($ref) === $protocol . 'paso1.php') ? 'welcome':'BIENVENIDO';  
} else {
    echo("<script>window.location = 'error.php';</script>");
}
 
     ?> `

Comment: ok, what happens when you access page2 by clicking a link from another page other than page1 ?

Comment: ok what happens is that it shows me the welcome message when I should send the error

Comment: well, I knew it ! My answer works great, the issue is that you were misplacing the the redirection in the script tag. Try this: `$ref = isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']:''; if(isset($ref[0])) {
     $protocol = strtolower(parse_url($ref)['scheme']) === 'https' ? 'https':'http';
     if(0 === strcmp(strtolower($ref), $protocol . '://paso1.php')) { echo 'BIENVENIDO'; }
     else { echo '<script>window.location = "error.php";</script>'; }
} else { echo '<script>window.location = "error.php";</script>'; }`

Comment: and by the way, why relying on `JavaScript` to do the redirection ? You can do it through `PHP` though. And as I said relying on `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` is a bad choice, implementing a tracking tool would be better, a `GET` variable containing the `URL` that led to this page is all what you need.