# How to use HTTP_REFERER in PHP

Tags: php, html, http-referer, index-error

I know this may be a duplicate of another link on here but I am not able to find a fix for my code.

I am trying to make a puzzle for my friends and family can try to do and I need a way to track what website they just came from so I know whether to send them to the next puzzle/win screen, or to send them to a page effectively saying they are cheaters. I am trying to use $_SERVER[HTTP_REFERER] to make this easier for me, but I want to echo out the address that the user is coming from to test my code, and I keep getting an index error.

**MY CODE:**

```
<?php
$_SERVERADDR=$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
echo "$_SERVERADDR";
?>
```

I keep getting an index error on this line `$_SERVERADDR=$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];`

Can anyone help out?

Comment: What do you get if you `echo "<pre>".print_r($_SERVER,1)."</pre>;"`? I mean, you are seeing the $_SERVER object?

Comment: @JohnTyner I put the information here: https://pastebin.com/cR5m2c5u

Comment: @Jax-p No, unfortunately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/60288899/7044855

Referrer isn't always set.  You can set HTTP headers manually if you're testing using curl/[postman](https://www.postman.com/)/etc, but not if you were testing by simply hitting your script in a browser.

[image: set referrer in postman]

Using this key/value combination you should see the following output

```php
<?php

$referer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];

echo $referer;
// https://google.com
```