# Redirecting user to tracking page if he came from different domain

Tags: .htaccess

Alright so I am making a tracking system where I would write down every user that came from a different domain (let's say that my domain is https://aaa.com) so any user that comes from any other website would first have to go "/tracking.php" and then I would do the rest via code.

Basically if HTTP_REFERER is not https://aaa.com then redirect the user to tracking.php page

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Document/referrer is you want to use a JS approach to this.

For php, a solution is been posted [PHP: How to get referrer URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16374704/php-how-to-get-referrer-url/16374737)

Comment: But I'd rather avoid JS and PHP for this.