# PHP Get Referrer - If Referrer Is An Application

Tags: php, mobile, referrer

We can get the referrer site with "$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']". However, if the incoming person clicked on the link in an application, how can I detect it? For example, how can I detect if the visitor came to my page by clicking on the link in the whatsapp message. Here, the link address clicked with "$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']" is obtained. How can I get the information that the person who came here has come from applications such as whatsapp, telegram, messenger.
Thanks.

Comment: You'd have to put something unique in the URL itself - if you control the link being used, that is. Or maybe the people at Google analytics and similar organisations have a solution for this. Sorry I'm not sure beyond that, I'm not convinced it's possible

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Sample explanation of the code I gave above is available in the link below. With this code, if the visitor comes to my site by clicking on the link on the browser, I can see from which site they came. But how can I find out the information that the visitor came via whatsapp when he clicks on the link in a whatsapp message?
https://stackoverflow.com/a/16374737/14597323