Get referral code from telegram bot start parameter with JavaScript landing page, and send to Laravel backend
I am making a telegram miniapp, it have options for users to refere others to the app and get reward,
I have completed the authentication and many functions/logics of the app. But extracting the referral code from the ref link eg: https://t.me/my_bot?start=RefC0d3, I have tried a lot of things that did not work
Please can someone help me out, Im stcucked here.
Thanks.
My js code is below:
const telegramWebApp = await loadTelegramSdk();
                if (telegramWebApp) {
                    const { id, first_name, username, start_param } = telegramWebApp.initDataUnsafe;
                    console.log('Telegram User Info:', { id, first_name, username, start_param });
    
                    const csrfToken = document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]')?.getAttribute('content');
    
                    const headers = {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    };
    
                    if (csrfToken) {
                        headers['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = csrfToken;
                    }
                    
                    const requestBody = {
                        ...telegramWebApp.initDataUnsafe,
                        referral_code: start_param // Add referral_code to the request body
                    };
    
                    const response = await fetch("{{ route('tg.authenticate') }}", {
                        method: 'POST',
                        headers: headers,
                        body: JSON.stringify(requestBody) // Send referral_code in the request body
                    });
    
                    const data = await response.json();
                    if (data.message === 'Logged in successfully' || data.message === 'User created and logged in') {
                        console.log(`Welcome ${first_name || username}!`);
                        setTimeout(() => {
                            window.location.href = '{{ route('tg.dashboard') }}'; // Redirect after 1.5 seconds
                        }, 1500);
                    } else {
                        console.error('Authentication failed:', data.message);
                    }
                }

In my controller I used Log::info('Request Input:', $request->all()); to check the inputs but the javasacipt is not sending the refferral code.

dear good developer. As you may forget, referrer url is not on request body, it's a part of server global variable like this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/16374737/5987259

Thanks for your response,
But is there a way I can get that like sending it via Webhook, I can handle it if I get it via webhook

oh, sorry. you mean that you want to get the value of start param? so you shoud set it on your bot at first and call your server url with that additionally

Don't worry, I've figured it out.
https://t.me/my_bot?start=Ref50D3 is sending a webhook with all the information I need including the referral code.
I stored the webhook payload, compared it when the user visited the app and extracted the user's data from the saved payload.
Thanks for your response. I appreciate.

do you succeed? @Hopekell

you should send in web hook requests' data what you need.

Yeah, I did, that worked perfectly.
