# Accept visitors from an uniqe referrer

Tags: php, referrer

Here is the deal
I want to accept visitors only from Google Search referrer to my site
So,if they type "domain.com" in the url bar, Google Search of "domain.com" must come up.
Can someone show me a Php code for this or something else?
Thanks

Comment: Can you please explain it more to a next level? What exactly you are looking for?

Comment: My visitors must come only from Google Search,not direct link. So when they type my domain in their browser, they must be redirect to the search results of my website. I think i should add some code in index.php but dont know what. I hope i was clear

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can i use $\_SERVER\['HTTP\_REFERER'\] to find that user came from google?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10613025/how-can-i-use-serverhttp-referer-to-find-that-user-came-from-google)

Comment: @TonyHensler well very close but not exactly. I dont want to know if they came from google or not. I want my website to be accessible only from Google and not from a direct link.

Comment: Example : news-worldx.com

Comment: Then you would need to add an if statement in the header in redirect the accordingly on the result of the $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']

Comment: check the referer header and if the use is not from google, redirect them to google search page result [URL](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=news-worldx.com). This can trigger google spam detection maybe. better to POST request to https://www.google.com/search

Comment: @SouravGhosh hmmm yes i thought it too about the spam. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can always check `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` and redirect them to https://www.google.co.in/search?q=yourwebsite.com if hey are not from google search page. But this is not efficient because this maybe can trigger Google spam detection. I am not completely sure about the spam detection, but I can suggest an alternative which is better in my opinion.

```
//say your website URL is example.com. Someone landed in example.com
$url = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
$host = parse_url ($url, PHP_URL_HOST);
if (strstr ($host, 'www.google.')) {
//someone can still spoof this. If you need more restriction, you need to check all google regional domains explicitly.
//https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Google_domains
    header('Location: example.com/welcome');
} else{
    header('Location: example.com/redirect');
}
```

Now in `redirect` page, you need to do the trick. You fill up a form automatically and submit it automatically using javascript.

```
<form id="myForm" action="https://www.google.com/search" method="get">
<input type="hidden" name="q" lang="en" value="example.com">
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
  document.getElementById('myForm').submit();
</script>
```

Now the users will be taken to the google search result page and your website will be the first result of course.

Comment: I will try it. Thank you

Comment: I mistakenly posted form method as `post, ` but it should be `get`. I tested my second code. It is working fine