# PHP PREG match error on finding a word in an fetched URL

Tags: php

i m trying to find out from which Source user visited using **REFERER** and **preg_match**

**My code goes as:**

***Getting source URL :***

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var a= (document.referrer);
</script>
<?php 
$previous_js = "<script>document.write(a)</script>";
?>
```

***Check whether the word exists in the URL to document:***

```
<?php
 $previous_jss = $previous_js;
     $google = 'google';
     $facebook = 'facebook';
     $instagram = 'instagram';
     $twitter = 'twitter';
     $pinterest = 'pinterest';
     $linkedin = 'linkedin';
     $youtube = 'youtube';

    if(preg_match("/{$google}/i", $previous_jss)) {
        $source = 'google';
    }elseif(preg_match("/{$facebook}/i", $previous_jss)) {
        $source = 'facebook';
    }elseif(preg_match("/{$instagram}/i", $previous_jss)) {
        $source = 'instagram';
    }elseif(preg_match("/{$twitter}/i", $previous_jss)) {
        $source = 'twitter';
    }elseif(preg_match("/{$pinterest}/i", $previous_jss)) {
         $source = 'pinterest';
    }elseif(preg_match("/{$linkedin}/i", $previous_jss)) {
         $source = 'linkedin';
    }elseif(preg_match("/{$youtube}/i", $previous_jss)) {
         $source = 'youtube';
    }else { $source = 'source'; }


echo $source; 
echo $previous_jss;
?>
```

However, when i echo `$previous_jss` it prints previous URL perfectly, but the `$source` variable gives out value 'source' no matter from where the redirection happen.

But when predefined the `$previous_jss`  variable to facebook.com or google.com, the `$source` variable gives out values correctly.

Couldn't understand what kind of logic i was missing all along here.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: PHP executes before javascript....in essence your variable `a` has not been written / determined when PHP writes `$previous_js = "<script>document.write(a)</script>";` ~ the variable `a` at this stage has no value as the javascript has not run

Comment: @RamRaider So, i have placed  `<script type="text/javascript">
    var a= (document.referrer);
</script>` at the bottom of the file, still the same result when redirected from a facebook post.

Comment: you could try sending `document.referrer` to a PHP script with ajax/fetch and then use the callback function to do whatever it is you need to do with that knowledge

Comment: It matters not that the javascript is at the top/middle or end of the html file. By the time that the browser is processing the javascript the PHP code has finished...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10613025/how-can-i-use-serverhttp-referer-to-find-that-user-came-from-google

Answer (score 1):

PHP already has a referer in the `$_SERVER` superglobal: `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`.

However, the [docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) state:

> The address of the page (if any) which referred the user agent to the
>   current page. This is set by the user agent. Not all user agents will
>   set this, and some provide the ability to modify HTTP_REFERER as a
>   feature. In short, it cannot really be trusted.

But I guess setting it via JS is as trustworthy, therefore it doesn't make much of a difference.

Also, your regular expressions aren't making any sense, since you're not using any of the features of regular expressions which would make them preferable over any string function.

In addition, you never use such a `else/if` construct. That's much more readable with `switch/case`. But in your case, I guess a loop would fit even better. Which would leave us with the following:

```
$referer = "unknown";
$sources = ("google","facebook","instagram","twitter","pinterest","linkedin","youtube");

for($sources as &$source)
{
    if(stripos($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], $source) !== false)
    {
        $referer = $source;
        break;
    }
}
```

To state the obvious: You should check for TLDs as well. Since currently, something like `https://mydomain.tld/wp/how-to-use-google` would cause the referer to be set as `google`, while it's not the case. Due to that, I'd recommend to really parse the URL and check the domain after the protocol. That's at least something you can do to avoid false positives.