# referring url in php

Tags: php

I am trying to setup  my 404 page to detect the referring url.
I would like to this in PHP any ideas?
thank you very much

Answer (score 4, accepted):

.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

Now, all your requests will be redirected to index.php
The requested uri segment will be available as `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`.
So just take that and look up that string in your db and do whatever you need to do with that.

---

Example:
I set up a test folder in my localhost environment, added the .htaccess and created a new index.php

```
<?php
$uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$segments = explode('/', $uri);
var_dump($segments['2']);
```

Sent your browser to: http://localhost/test/123/foo and it will print

```
string '123' (length=3)
```

Now you have your string in $segments['2']. Use that in your db query.
As easy as that.

Comment: Err, if you put it in subfolder test, you should of course change that in the .htaccess as well. Just sayin..

Comment: thank you very much for the detailed example. Just a quick question with regards to regex in this case . what I have so far is general, how do I turn the following : 
RewriteRule ^entry/([^/\.]+)/?$ entry/?id=$1 [L] to something that takes only integers. that folder should have other files in it but I want the mod_rewrite to work only for integer entires. Thank you

Comment: The two rewrite conditions mean, to only execute the rewrite rule if neither a file nor directory with that name exist. So calling /add.php for example will call it normally. In short: Whenever you call anything, that doesnt exist, it will get sent to index.php. I would advise to check if an entry exists in the db for that value and if it doesnt redirect to some 404 page. I would also strongly recommend to run the value through mysql_real_escape_string() before putting it in a query.

Answer (score 4):

```
<?php
$referer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
?>
```

Note: Don't rely too much on this data as easily can be faked.

In your apache2.conf (or .htaccess)

`ErrorDocument 404 /your_error_dir/your_error_file.php`

**Update:**

`http://ex.am/c8N4j`

Your [mod_rewrite](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=mod_rewrite) should detect the given parameter: `c8N4j`
Your PHP script should search the given parameter in your database and if it's found it should redirect user to the actual page.

Comment: I think the question is how to setup Apache so that php code can be executed in his 404 page (which by default is just a static 404.htm page).

Comment: sorry I should have given more details. I would like to setup a  url shortening system. and i am going about doing it by creating shortcut that can be detected in my 404 page ( i am assuming that it can run php just like any other page on the server). So what I need is the refering url so I can decipher it to redirect to the right URL so a link should look like  index/123456 ...since such link doesnt exist the user would be rerouted to the 404 page which should read that link and translate to the corresponding page. I might be going completely the wrong way but this is the idea so far. thanks

Comment: Sorry i don't understand your logic. Your shortcut (ideally) has nothing to do with 404.

Answer (score 2):

did you mean?

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']
```

> The address of the page (if any) which
>   referred the user agent to the current
>   page. This is set by the user agent.
>   Not all user agents will set this, and
>   some provide the ability to modify
>   HTTP_REFERER as a feature. In short,
>   it cannot really be trusted.it cannot really be trusted.

Take a look also at [Determining Referer in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/165975/determining-referer-in-php)