# How to detect if link is from a particular domain

Tags: php

I need to be able to detect with PHP if a link is from a particular domain. I can not just check if domain is present in the link because it can be faked by appending domain.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you are looking for? It's possible that you just need to use `parse_url()`.

Answer (score 3):

Just use **parse_url()** as konforce mentioned. For example:

```
$url = "http://www.google.com/";
$parts  = parse_url ($url);

print $parts["host"];   // will print www.google.com

// Or, for PHP 5.1 and above
$host =  parse_url ($url, PHP_URL_HOST); // returns www.google.com
```

Now, the good thing about this is that appending the domain to the end of an url like this:

```
http://www.google.com/?www.foo.com
```

Wont work as the **host** element will still say that the link points to www.google.com and not www.foo.com.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you'd want check the referrer and make sure you check with double forward slashes, since that's part of the protocol (HTTP/HTTPS) and can't be faked.

Check this link for extra reference: [Determining Referer in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/165975/determining-referer-in-php)

I would check against something like...

> //www.mydomain.com
>
> //mydomain.com

Comment: No, actually i need to detect a link in a post and then analyze what the domain is. Thanks.

Comment: My mistake. The post above helps for that I believe.