# How to activate http referer from server / cpanel?

Tags: http-referer

My issue is about `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`. I can't get the value of `http_referer` on my server or may be due to Firefox. But I've also printed `print_r($_SERVER);` but still it doesn't provide me previous page's link.

Answer (score 0):

This is directly from [PHP.net](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)

> The address of the page (if any) which referred the user agent to the current page. This is set by the user agent. Not all user agents will set this, and some provide the ability to modify HTTP_REFERER as a feature. In short, it cannot really be trusted.

I'm thinking it may be a firefox issue. What version are you using?

Comment: thanks for answering k4t434sis .. but actually its not a solution i think.

Comment: I would suggest implementing $_SESSION vars that record the previous page's $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] if you cannot solve this quick. I've personally never had that global come back null, that's why I'm thinking it's a browser issue (possibly something Firefox will fix after 6 comes out of beta). Also check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/165975/determining-referer-in-php#answer-166005