# How to go referer page using php

Tags: php

How to go to referer page using php...

I used `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` to go back but I cant go to last second page where I was before.

It only stores the last page, not the second last one.
I dont want to use javascript.

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/165975/determining-referer-in-php] [1] duplicate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep track of all pages the user visited and use it as a stack to determine the previous page.

That's your only option. Don't go there.

The answer: you can't.

Answer (score 0):

i don't know why you used `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` to go back.
you will do this with javascript too :

```
window.history.go(-1)
```

where `-1` is to go one page back.

Comment: I dont want to use javascript.

Comment: @RohanKumar then you have to follow the answer of Tom van der