# Get the domain name with SOAP Server

Tags: php, soap, dns

I need to get the domain from which the SOAP Client is being used so I was wondering if anyone knows how to get it without the use of: `$_SERVER['HOST_NAME']` and get it from the headers or something like that because I need to know exactly from which it comes and not pass some params that can be edit.

Well thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you wondering about how they're calling the server, or where they're coming from?  HOST_NAME is the name they called the server when they contacted it.  You want REMOTE_ADDR for the client, and then do a DNS lookup on them (or whois if that fails, to at least identify the owner of the ip block)

Answer (score 0):

For the Server side you can use $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], But I would read this thread first:

[Determining Referer in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/165975/determining-referer-in-php)

Comment: Are there HTTP referers involved with SOAP requests?

Comment: If they are done over http (most common use of soap) then yes.

Comment: But now that I think about it, you one might only be able to get the IP address not the domain $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

Comment: I would say so, too after reading the question again. OP asks from the server point of view and wants to learn about the client host (and not about a previous request of the client - if any).