# How do I Get a URI segment from the CodeIgniter view where an Ajax request is made?

Tags: ajax, codeigniter, jquery, controller, uri

I'm using jQuery to call a method of my "volunteer" CodeIgniter controller from a view called "edit" that takes a single parameter, "id"

The URI of the view is:
`volunteer/edit/3`

I make the call of my `update()` method like so:

```
$.post('volunteer/update', function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

All the method does right now is echo a URI segment:

```
public function update(){
    echo $this->uri->segment(2, 0);
}
```

What is want is a segment of the URI of the view where `update()` is called (the "edit" view). Instead, I get a segment of the URI of `update()`. How can I get a segment of the edit view's URI so that I can use it within the `update()` method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to pass in the segment value in the POST data of the AJAX call.

Your options are:

1) You can parse the URL w/ JavaScript to determine what the value of the segment is, for example:

```
<script>
var postData;
// assign whatever other data you're passing in
postData.lastSegment = window.location.href.substr(window.location.href.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
$.post('volunteer/update', postData, function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});
</script>
```

2) You can use PHP to pre-populate a JavaScript variable in the view that you can then use in the POST

```
<script>
var postData;
// assign whatever other data you're passing in
postData.lastSegment = <?php echo $this->uri->segment(2, 0); ?>;
$.post('volunteer/update', postData, function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});
</script>
```

And finally in the `update()` controller, you can pull out the data out of the POST with `$this->input->post()` or out of `$_POST`.

Comment: I ended up just using a hidden input, but it basically the same thing as doing Daemon's second suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

You could fetch the referrer URL by using

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']
```

and than parse it manually to get your segment.

It's not 100% secure, as it can be overriden (its set as an header by the server).

Se more details on this older [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/165975/determining-referer-in-php)