# Determining the Source of $_POST

Tags: php

Is there an easy way to find out the source of a post variable in PHP?

#### Form on example.com/formone.php

```
<form method="post" action="test.php">
<input name="myusername"type="text">
<input name="mypassword" type="password">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

#### Form on example.com/formtwo.php

```
<form method="post" action="test.php">
<input name="myusername"type="text">
<input name="mypassword" type="password">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

I understand that I could use a hidden input, but I was wondering if PHP had a method to test the source of the POST.

Comment: Maybe addressing *why* you need to know the referring page would be useful. You may not need to at all.

Comment: I'm working on a very rudimentary controller type file.  It was mostly curiosity.  ie, not security related in the slightest.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

While you could potentially use the HTTP_REFERER server variable, [it is not very reliable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/166005/1028949).  Your best bet would be to use a hidden field.

Another alternative would be to switch out your submit `input` for a submit `button`.  This way you can pass a value with it, retain the button's label, and test for that inside your `test.php` page:

```
<button name="submit" type="submit" value="form1">Submit</button>
```

In your PHP file you would then test:

```
if( $_POST['submit'] == "form1" )
    // do something
```

Comment: Exactly what I wanted to know.  I really like the button value approach and will probably continue down that path.

Comment: @MobyD: Note that button `value`s are only sent if it is actually clicked (or focused when the form is submitted), submitting by pressing "enter" while focused in a text field will not send the value, you might want to use hidden inputs.

Comment: @WesleyMurch Thank you for the wise comment.

Comment: @WesleyMurch You are absolutely right.  I probably would have never figured that out and been quite distraught for about a week.  Hidden values it is.