# Prevent direct access of a fancybox iframe content via url

Tags: php, javascript, fancybox-2

Is there any solution that prevent an access to any content that is made to be called via fancybox iframe only?

I am using fancybox ver 2.0 and PHP as a server end programming.

Have a look for example.

```
<a href="feedback.php" class="feedback fancybox.iframe">Feedback</a>
```

Now generally when a user clicks on feedback link, fancybox will handle the request.

But I want to prevent users from accessing "feedback.php" page directly from the browser's address bar.

Comment: You mean something like this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/165975/determining-referer-in-php

=P

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])){
    header("Location: ".$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);}
else {
   header("Location: index.php");
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, with some changes in your code I can prevent direct execution of feedback page! But I would also like to prevent ctrl+click access to the feedback page without affecting fancybox.

Comment: I can not understand you explain better?