# how to block the content of iframes from browser calls

Tags: php, iframe, block

Is it possible to block iframe's contents for calling from browser alone?

For example;

`domain.com/index.php` has `iframe.php` in it.

```
index.php
```

has session also `iframe.php` has. But when session start, user can call `iframe.php` as

```
domain.com/iframe.php
```

Comment: You mean *block `iframe.php` to be accessed directly* though address bar?

Comment: yes exactly I want to do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If *javascript* is an option, you may detect if `iframe` is opened in browser directly:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if (top.location == self.location) {
    top.location = "http://homepage.com";
}
</script>
```

Another option is a usage of [`$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`](http://php.net/$_SERVER), as mentioned [*here*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13486643/prevent-direct-access-of-a-fancybox-iframe-content-via-url).

Comment: javascript solves my problem. I will check other option too. Thank you.