# redirect users using $_GET

Tags: php, redirect, get

i have a php page **"view.php"**

but i want no one to view the page direct by hitting or manually typing www.domain.com/view.php , it must come from index.php undergoing some process. ie

```
index.php ==> view.php/id=$$$
```

i tried for **$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];**

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] =='www.domain.com/view.php')
header("location: index.php");
```

but aint worked..

can any one please help

Comment: Why don't you use .htaccess? The server request uri is not reliable.

Comment: @thatidiotguy  the session variables are printed on view.php from index.php , is it still fine if i go with htaccess.. please suggest

Comment: as @thatidiotguy says, server request uri is unreliable. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/165975/determining-referer-in-php If you control the previous page that the user was on you could set a cookie or something in a session then check if that exist/is the correct value on you view.php

Comment: Put it outside the document root & let index.php include it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to send it trough a form in your index.php file using a POST variable

```
<form action="view.php" method="post">
<input type="hidden" vaue="test" name="KEY"/>
</form>
```

in your view.php

```
if(isset($_POST['key'])){
//LOAD FILE
}
```

there are different solutions though

Answer (score 0):

$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] returns site root-relative path, i.e. "/view.php" or "/folder/file.php". So your code should be `if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] == "/view.php") { /* ... */ }`. It is also recommended to place `exit();` after redirection headers to prevent subsequent code execution.

You can also use $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"] like this `if(!$_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"] == "http://www.your-domain.com/index.php") { /* ... */ }`

For further information, please refer to http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php