# HTTP_REFERER the same site but works in Javascript?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to capture the `HTTP_REFERER` using PHP when clicking in from Google. If I print it out on the page after coming through, it says the referrer is the same site as I'm on.

I would assume it's being redirected, but if I type `document.referrer` in the console, it correctly shows Google.co.uk. What is going on here?

Comment: Can you please share code snippet you're using?

Comment: Literally just `die(var_dump($_SERVER))`

Comment: Have a look at this answer 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/165975/determining-referer-in-php/#answer-166005

Comment: That's not a concern in this case. It's how we done it in the past and it has worked fine up until now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so this is really annoying. I found out what was causing it: My browser had a plugin that modified referrer information. Apparently it didn't do so in Javascript so both ended up different.

Comment: And there you have just another reason why the referrer can not be relied on _at all_.

Comment: And again: I'm perfectly aware it cannot be relied on. But it's the job at hand so I can't really palm it off as it 'worked' fine before.