# Is there a reliable way to get the referring url without relying on $_SERVER?

Tags: php, google-analytics

I'm customizing the content of my site based on Google and Bing PPC campaigns. If a user clicks a PPC ad, they see certain content. If they come to the site via organic seach, they see different content. If they come direct, they see a third content.
It's working but not consistently; results are not behaving as expected, and often PPC ads will show the organic content.
I know HTTP_REFERER can't be trusted, so maybe this is causing the problem.
In any case, is there a better way to do this? Can I use Google Analytics and/or something in https://code.google.com/p/gapi-google-analytics-php-interface/ to reliably get the referring URL?
Thanks for any advice.

Comment: No. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/165975/determining-referer-in-php

Comment: @mkaatman you've summed it up quite nicely in just 3 characters =)

Comment: My question isn't whether I can use HTTP_REFERER, it's whether I can use Google analytics or something else. I get it if the answer's no, but that link only tells me what I already know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Showing different content based on whether the user clicked to your site from a search engine or typed the URL in directly is not possible without using `$_SERVER`, and even using `$_SERVER` is unreliable since it can easily be forged. However as far as I know, providing different content to search engines (also known as cloaking) is a quick way to get your site banned and/or penalized anyway. So I would avoid this at all costs.

For the CPC ad campaign, this is easy. Just set a different URL, eg http://www.yoursite.com/?cpc=adwords, then if `$_GET['cpc']` is set, set a session variable and redirect them to the same page but without the `$_GET` parameter. Of course, session cookies could also be deleted/disabled, so even this is not 100% reliable.