# Get Source/Medium of visitor

Tags: php

I know it's possible to get the previous url of the visitor with

`$ _SERVER ['HTTP_REFERER'];`

but how do I get the source/medium that the visitor was before accessing the site?

For example if the visitor came from: Google/Organic, Google/CPC (paid), Bing/Organic, Bing/CPC, Direct/none, facebook/referral, youtube/referral, otherSites.com/referral, etc.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a reliable way to get the referring url without relying on $\_SERVER?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26721402/is-there-a-reliable-way-to-get-the-referring-url-without-relying-on-server)

Comment: @AlisterBulman Thanks for replying, I visited the possible duplicate question link, but the question you suggested does not answer my doubt

Comment: There's no standard way of getting the "medium" (a term invented by Google Analytics). You have to read the referrer and deviate the medium from it.

Comment: @Reeno thank you very much I found the solution, see my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution on GitHub: [Google Analytics Cookie Parser PHP](https://github.com/jamesflight/Google-Analytics-Cookie-Parser-PHP)

Basically I must parse some Google Analytics cookies, for example `utma` and `umtz`, and access the information I need

**For utma**

```
$utma->time_of_first_visit; // DateTime
$utma->time_of_last_visit; // DateTime
$utma->time_of_current_visit; // DateTime
$utma->session_count // Integer
```

**For utmz**

```
$utmz->timestamp; // DateTime
$utmz->session_count // Integer
$utmz->campaign_number // Integer
$utmz->source // string
$utmz->medium // string
$utmz->campaign // string
$utmz->term // string
$utmz->content // string
```