# Showing raw URL in IIS PHP 404 page

Tags: php, iis

I am using IIS and PHP. I have a custom 404 page which is a PHP script. On this page, I would like to display the original URL accessed. I am trying the following text plus server variable but it is just showing the site name and HTTP_REFERER is usually blank.

```
echo 'http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
```

What is the correct server variable(s) to use to get the raw URL in PHP/IIS.

This is the appropriate section in my web.config to call the custom 404 page:

```
<httpErrors>
  <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />
  <error statusCode="404" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="/404.php" responseMode="Redirect" />
</httpErrors>
```

Comment: *"and HTTP_REFERER is usually blank"* - That shouldn't be relied upon. Have a read here http://stackoverflow.com/a/6023980/

Comment: agreed, but what should I use in its place? Don't forget IIS has sent the browser to this page because the original page could not be found.

Comment: Unfortunately Rob, I know nothing about IIS. See if this answer helps http://stackoverflow.com/a/13703882/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than use a redirect I do an ExecuteURL

```
<error statusCode="404" path="/404.php" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
```

and for the variables to describe the page

```
echo 'http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```