# URL Mapping and redirect with input in php

Tags: php, url, redirect, url-routing, url-mapping

I get things working with help by styfle, and now I have this working:
olympiccode.xyz/download/plugin/hgjg/ff olympiccode.xyz/download/plugin/anything/here

Now I want to redirect by the input on the URL, for example, if a person used this URL: olympiccode.xyz/download/plugin/anything/here How I can redirect him to olympiccode.xyz/download/files/pl/anything-here.jar (the anything-here.jar is changed by what the person put in the URL)

//Old question

I don't know the name of this things so I used "Custom automatic URL", what I mean is some links like those:

```
https://crafatar.com/capes/jeb_
https://crafatar.com/capes/Notch
---
https://inventivetalent.org/download/plugin/Test/1.5
https://inventivetalent.org/download/plugin/CustomUrl/1.345344.345345
```

How it work? is it really done with javascript? how I can do it?
[/spoiler]

Comment: That URL system where you can write whatever you want and always will generate a page with the info based on what you write

Answer (score 1):

I sounds like you want to handle [URL Routing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_framework#URL_mapping) (sometimes called URL Mapping) with javascript.

It's unclear if you want to do server-side routing with node.js, or if you want to do client-side routing in the browser so I will link an isomorphic router which works in both environments called [director](https://github.com/flatiron/director).

Performing routing in the browser was typically restricted to `window.location.hash` for urls like http://example.com/#about and http://example.com/#downloads.

However, HTML5 provides a History API to rewrite the URL as http://example.com/about and http://example.com/downloads

Read more about the [history.pushState()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API) on MDN.

Comment: I now get it working on my website with:
http://olympiccode.xyz/download/plugin/hgjg/ff/
http://olympiccode.xyz/download/plugin/anything/here/

But for example, if a person used this URL:
http://olympiccode.xyz/download/plugin/anything/here/
How I can redirect him to http://olympiccode.xyz/download/files/pl/anything-here.jar
(the anything-here.jar is changed by what the person put in the URL)

Comment: I think what you want is a [Redirect](http://stackoverflow.com/q/768431/266535)

Comment: But how I can get what the user put in the URL?

Comment: Try the [HTTP_REFERER](http://stackoverflow.com/q/165975/266535) header