# how to get the value of page url in email through contact form submissiojn in html javascript php

Tags: javascript, php

Actually, My website has lots of pages so when customer send me his query via on-page contact form option and submit it to me I want the address of the current page on which he filled the contact form and send to me. ex www.website.com/page/page44 so I want to get this URL also with contact form mail submission Please help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get current URL with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406192/get-current-url-with-jquery)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/165975/determining-referer-in-php might be useful. Or if you want something more reliable, put something to identify the current page as a hidden field in your contact form.