# Redirect to another page outside of Iframe in php

Tags: php, redirect, iframe

While standing in an Iframe, can we redirect to a page outside of Iframe (target page is on a different domain)?

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: before landing on the main page in iframe, I want to verify the request(by using Http_Referer or public-private keys). If request is not verified, I want to redirect to the parent page.

Comment: You mean you want to allow certain sites to embed your site in an iframe?

Comment: Yes, and If a I don't want to allow that certain site then it should be redirected to that site

Comment: So you could check if the site is authentic using `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`. If it doesn't match with any of your data, you could probably send `X-Frame-Options: sameorigin` header which would avoid loading your site in their iframe. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options

Comment: **Update:** `HTTP_REFERER` isn't reliable as it is sent from the client's browser.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/165975/determining-referer-in-php 
You would probably want to have embed links like how google or youtube does. However, anyone with your embed link could use it. So I presume this doesn't satisfy your business need. You may have to change your strategy.

Comment: @vivek_23 Thanks, I found another thing, instead of sending back to from where request was coming, I redirect it to an error page inside my iframe showing error details.